# C# Regex Match parenthesis group except if it contains specified word

Tags: c#, regex

I have a long string:

(Today is a blue day) (Today is a good day) (Today is a **BAD** day) (Today is a green day) (Today is a blue day)

I want to match the parentheses groups, except if it contains the capitalized word.  The word will always be fully capitalized, but may not be the only fully capitalized word - but will be the only word that is exactly BAD.

I have a very long string and I want to change the parentheses groups that do not contain the word BAD while leaving BAD alone. I was hoping to avoid iterating over every single parentheses group to check if it contains BAD.

This: `\(.+?\)`

Will match my parentheses groups.

I have tried:

`\(.+?(?=\bBAD\b).+?\)` - this matches every group up to the group containing BAD.

`(?=\bBAD\b).+?\)` - this matches the end of the group "BAD day)"

I tried a few variations of negative lookbehinds but could not get them to provide a result.

I know this works:

```
\(.[^BAD]+?\)
```

Until you include (Today is a Blue day) - and then it fails.

Anyone know an effective way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\((?>([^()]*\bBAD\b)?)[^()]*\)(?(1)(?!))
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%28%28%3F%3E%28%5B%5E%28%29%5D*%5CbBAD%5Cb%29%3F%29%5B%5E%28%29%5D*%5C%29%28%3F%281%29%28%3F!%29%29&i=%28Today%20is%20a%20blue%20day%29%20%28Today%20is%20a%20good%20day%29%20%28Today%20is%20a%20BAD%20day%29%20%28Today%20is%20a%20green%20day%29%20%28Today%20is%20a%20blue%20day%29). *Details*:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?>([^()]*\bBAD\b)?)` - an atomic group (that disallows re-trying its pattern when backtracking occurs): zero or more chars other than `)` and `(` and then a whole word `BAD`, all captured into Group 1
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `(?(1)(?!))` - if Group 1 was matched, trigger backtracking (here, it will fail the match since we used an atomic group before).

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/FKEOq0):

```cs
var text = "(Today is a blue day) (Today is a good day) (Today is a BAD day) (Today is a green day) (Today is a blue day)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"\((?>([^()]*\bBAD\b)?)[^()]*\)(?(1)(?!))")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Output:

```
(Today is a blue day)
(Today is a good day)
(Today is a green day)
(Today is a blue day)
```

Comment: That is very interesting, so in the if clause at the end you can drop the match as `(?!)` is always false and the atomic group prevents backtracking to the optional capture group right?

Comment: @Thefourthbird `(?!)` = PCRE's `(*FAIL)`, it signals failure to the regex engine at that exact place, and if there are indefinitely quantified subpatterns before that point, backtracking will trigger, unless we tell backtracking to mind its own business with atomic groups. So, it is basically the same logic as with a simple lookahead, but using a conditional construct with a capturing group that is only matched once.

Comment: Thank you works perfectly, and was definitely above my paygrade in terms of Regex - don't think I would have ever got there on my own.

Answer (score 1):

This part `(?=\bBAD\b).+?\)` asserts BAD to the right and then matches as least as possible till the next `)`. It can also be written without the lookahead `\bBAD\b.+?\)`

This part `[^BAD]` matches any character except the characters `B` `A` `D`

You can use the opposite using a negative lookahead instead to asser that BAD is not between parenthesis, and you might also add word boundaries `\b` to prevent a partial match.

```
\((?![^()]*\bBAD\b[^()]*\))[^()]*\)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(?![^()]*\bBAD\b[^()]*\))` Negative lookahead, assert not optional parenthesis followed by the word BAD till the first closing parenthesis to the right
- `[^()]*` Match 0+ times any char except `(` `)` using a negated character class
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1PPc3L/1)